# An optimization problem inspired by a result about Centroidal Voronoi Tessellations. How to deal with the Nonlinear case?

Tags: convex-optimization

**For Centroidal Voronoi Tessellations we have the following result:**

Let $\rho(\mathbf{y})$ be the probability density function on the open set
$\Omega \in \mathbf{R}^{\mathbf{N}}$ over
which is found the sets of $k$ points $\{ \mathbf{z}_i \}_{i=1}^k$ and $k$ regions $\{ V_i \}_{i=1}^k$ that tessellate $\Omega$
. The functional
$$
F( (\mathbf{z}_i,V_i,i=1,\cdots,k) )=\sum_{i=1}^{k} \int_{\mathbf{y} \in V_i} \rho(\mathbf{y}) |\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{z}_i|^2 \mathrm{d} \mathbf{y}
$$
is minimized when the set over $\Omega$
is a Voronoi tessellation with $\{ \mathbf{z}_i \}_{i=1}^k$ as the centroids of
the Voronoi regions $\{ V_i \}_{i=1}^k$
$$
\mathbf{z}_i=\dfrac{\int_{\mathbf{y} \in V_i}\mathbf{y}\rho(\mathbf{y})\mathrm{d} \mathbf{y}}{\int_{\mathbf{y} \in V_i}\rho(\mathbf{y})\mathrm{d} \mathbf{y}}
$$

**The question is, for a nonlinear target function**
$$
F( (\mathbf{z}_i,V_i,i=1,\cdots,k) )=\sum_{i=1}^{k} \int_{\mathbf{y} \in V_i} \rho(\mathbf{y}) e^{|\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{z}_i|}|\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{z}_i|^2 \mathrm{d} \mathbf{y}
$$
**how to minimize it with varying $\{\mathbf{z}_i \}_{i =1}^k$?**